# Change format of date from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: perl

How would I change 02/01/1999 to 1999-02-01 using perl? Ive tried this but it is returning DATE IS -00-00

```
sub changeDate{
    my $date = shift;
    my @adate=split (/\//, $date);
    my $ndate=$adate[2]."-".sprintf("%02d", $adate[1])."-".sprintf("%02d",$adate[0]);
    say "DATE IS $ndate";   
    return $ndate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is correct.

```
$ perl -e'
    use feature qw( say );

    sub changeDate{
        my $date = shift;
        my @adate=split (/\//, $date);
        my $ndate=$adate[2]."-".sprintf("%02d", $adate[1])."-".sprintf("%02d",$adate[0]);
        return $ndate;
    }

    say changeDate("02/01/1999");
'
1999-01-02
```

You must have passed something other than `02/01/1999` to `changeDate`.

Note that `changeDate` can be reduce to the following:

```
sub changeDate { sprintf '%3$d-%1$02d-%2$02d', split /\//, shift }
```

Comment: yes I found the problem, I was calling the sub incorrectly